# Change Value of Instance Variable in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an instance variable in my controller and would like to increment it's value with Javascript.  Am I able to do this?  If so, how and where do I put this Javascript file?

A simple counter is all that I'm looking for.  I'm not sure if I should look into calling AJAX instead.  I need this to be done on the client-side without any page refreshes.

Comment: Please tell more about the functionality that you want. There are many many ways to accomplish this.

Comment: just a simple counter really.  the goal is to create a dynamic scrolling twitter feed.  most importantly, it has to be done on client-side without page refreshes.  thanks.

Comment: What do u mean by with `javascript`, is that js run on serverside or client side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update variable dynamically within Rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636679/how-to-update-variable-dynamically-within-rails-app)

Comment: This is duplicate found over here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636679/how-to-update-variable-dynamically-within-rails-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to use Ajax to update your variable in controller. But I'm not sure how flexible an instance variable for this.

But have your variable in the session instead. Simple work flow  will be:

you have a session variable

```
session[:counter] = 0
```

you have the increment code in the controller

```
def increment_session
  session[:counter] += 1
end
```

and you will call the '`increment_session`' via, AJAX from your view

assuming you are using Rails < 3, the following are some useful links for implementing AJAX call:

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=19606

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cb12056/

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote

Comment: thanks.  i ended up using json to manipulate the data with javascript